# Insert an array into MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a PHP form with 3 fields `name`, `date`, `school`. Associated with them are up to 40 `college`, `coursetitle`, `coursenumber`s.

I want the insert SQL to be:

```
INSERT INTO _some_table_
  (name, date, school, college, coursetitle, coursenumber) 
VALUES
  (foo, 2011-12-23, UCLA, BizSchool, Accounting, XXX0000),
  (foo, 2011-12-23, UCLA, BizSchool, Accounting, XXX0000),
  (foo, 2011-12-23, UCLA, BizSchool, Accounting, XXX0000),
  (foo, 2011-12-23, UCLA, BizSchool, Accounting, XXX0000),
  (foo, 2011-12-23, UCLA, BizSchool, Accounting, XXX0000),
  (foo, 2011-12-23, UCLA, BizSchool, Accounting, XXX0000);
```

etc. and I don't want to include any rows where the `coursetitle` is blank. I'm having a tough time with the array!

Comment: Where does the college info come from? You want to add 40 rows per 1 form submit? Sounds like wrong abstraction.

Comment: Need to look at normalizing your tables. Have a table for names, colleges, courses and then a table that links them all together. If you want to stick with what you have, could you show the array of data that you're working with?

Comment: Where is the array ? can you show your PHP code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want do this as an array you have to mix it with the session instead so session will contain your array values. So the inserting query will be inside your looping.

Can you copy your code? Or you want me to code the example ? Thanks

Comment: To use an array you have to use the session ? sorry what ?

Comment: How can you add your value into array as dynamic value ? I gave the solution and mix it between array and session so that when user already want to commit the values into the table of database. So user can able to commit the database. Like transaction for simple example :) I hope you got what I mean

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQLI, it could be something like this:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new Mysqli('localhost','root','pass','db');

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO _some_table(name, date, school, college, coursetitle, coursenumber) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

/**
 * ITERATE VALUES, EACH KEY IN ARRAY CORRESPONDS TO A NEW ROW, THAT HAS TO BE INSERTED.
 */
foreach($values as $arr) {
    if (!empty($arr['coursetitle'])) {
        extract($arr);
        /*
         * BIND THE VALUES TO BE INSERTED TO THE STATEMENT
         */
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $name, $date, $school, $college, $coursetitle, $coursenumber);
        $stmt->execute(); // Execute statement
    }
}

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

this ofcourse is assuming you are using an associative array with keys that equals the column names.

You can read more about prepared statements [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Answer (score 0):

Are you just having problems getting the POST array? When you write the html, you can do something like:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Course: </td><td><input type="text" name="coursetitle[]" value="" /></td>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
        <td>Course Number: </td><td><input type="text" name="coursenum[]" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3"><h3>Add Another:</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>College: </td><td><input type="text" name="college[]" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Course: </td><td><input type="text" name="coursetitle[]" value="" /></td>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
        <td>Course Number: </td><td><input type="text" name="coursenum[]" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>College: </td><td><input type="text" name="college[]" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And you can make as many of those as you want
Then handle it with PHP like this:

```
$i = 0;
$complete = 0;
$query = "INSERT INTO TABLE (name, date, school, college, coursetitle, coursenumber) VALUES ";
foreach($_POST['coursetitle'] AS $course) {
    $title = trim($course);
    if (!empty($title)) {
        $college = trim($_POST['college'][$i]);
        $num = trim($_POST['coursenum'][$i]);
        $query .= "('foo', '" . date("Y-m-d") . "', 'UCLA' '{$college}', '{$title}', '{$num}'),";
    $complete++;
    }

    $i++;
}

$query = substring($query, 0, strlen($query) - 1); // Removes last comma from query
if ($complete == 0) {
    echo "No colleges were posted, or none of the course titles were completed.";
    exit;
} else {
    $query .= ";";
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

Or something like that :)

Comment: Thanks! Got it using foreach/if(empty).